# jQuery datatable buttons (Excel) set height of row on Excel format

Tags: jquery, xml, datatables

I am trying to figure out how to setting height of row on customize jQuery datatable buttons (Excel).

This is my code:

```
customize: function (xlsx: any) {
    // more code
    let rels = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
    // set height for all col
    window.$(`row`, rels).attr('ss:Height', '100');
    // more code
}
```

but it doesn't work & doesn't affect my Excel file..

Can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change this:

```
window.$(`row`, rels).attr('ss:Height', '100');
```

to

```
$('row, rels').attr('ss:Height', '100');
```

Since JQuery (at least one websites) uses strings to select elements.